# Count runs lazily in Python translate from Haskell

Tags: python, haskell, generator, code-translation, lazy-sequences

I'm trying to write a generator function (or achieve the equivalent) which takes an iterable `xs` in Python and counts the "runs". (This is a problem in *Thinking Functionally with Haskell* by Bird, which I want to translate into Python using Python's laziness features.) So

```py
list(iter(count_runs(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'd'])))
# => [(2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, c'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'd')]
```

In Haskell it's

```hs
countRuns :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
countRuns [] = []
countRuns x:xs = (1 + length us, x):countRuns vs
               where us, vs = span (==x) xs
```

In Python,  I'd like to write somethin like

```py
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def count_runs(xs):
  # get first element x of xs, if it exists
  us, vs = (takewhile(lambda y: y==x, xs), 
            dropwhile(lambda y: y==x, xs))
  yield (1 + len(list(us)), x)
  yield from count_runs(vs)
```

But the problem is that `vs` is an iterator already, so I will run into trouble if I call `takewhile` and `dropwhile` on it in the next recursion. (When I call `list(takewhile(..., xs))` in the next recursion, it will get rid of the first element of `dropwhile(..., xs)` as well, because they're both looking at the same iterator.

How can I fix this issue, and what is the correct way to get the first element in the second line?

Comment: `itertools.tee()` perhaps?

Comment: You don't really need `takewhile` and `dropwhile`, because Python iterators are mutable. However, `takewhile` also isn't using pattern-matching, so it will consume a non-`x` value from `xs` in order to stop yielding values.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` already does most of the work you need for this.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused. If the problem is that doing `takewhile` will cause `dropwhile` to start where you want the next `takewhile` to start, then just... don't call `dropwhile` at all? `us = takewhile(lambda y: y==x, xs); yield (1+len(list(us)), x); yield from count_runs(xs)` (Not putting this in an answer because I don't know Python and so there could be a subtle reason not to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A significant difference between `span` and `takewhile` is that `takewhile` consumes the first non-`x` value in order to determine when to stop yielding values. As a result, you'll lose any singleton items in the input; in particular, `takewhile` loses the first `b` in producing the leading set of `a`s. The iterator protocol has no way of peeking at the next element of an iterator, nor does it have a way to put back an element it consumes.

Instead, you'll need two independent iterators: one for `takewhile` to produce the desired prefix, and another from which to *drop* that prefix for the recursive call.

```
def count_runs(xs):
    try:
        x = next(xs)
    except StopIteration:
        return

    t1, t2 = tee(xs)

    us = list(takewhile(lambda y: y == x, t1))
    yield (1 + len(us), x)
    yield from count_runs(dropwhile(lambda y: y == x, t2))
```

(Note that the `itertools` documentation implements something similar to `span` in its [recipe section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) as a `before_and_after` function. It doesn't use `tee`, but I refer you to the actual implementation for details).

```
def before_and_after(xs):
    ...

def count_runs(xs):
    try:
        x = next(xs)
    except StopIteration:
        return

    first, second = before_and_after(lambda y: y == x, xs)
    yield (1 + len(list(first)), x)
    yield from count_runs(second)
```

)

However, most of this work is already done for you by `itertools.groupby`.

```
def count_runs(xs):
    yield from ((len(list(v)), k) for k, v in groupby(xs))
```

Comment: If you want to avoid creating lists just to take their length, you could replace that bit with `sum(1 for _ in v)`